# How can I compile different files to different folders, in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Picture this: I've got `main.ts` and `sw.ts`.

How can I compile `main.ts` to `js/` folder and `sw.ts` to `root` directory? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the solution with the help of this page: [Projects References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html).

## Step-by-step

### First

What worked for me was creating a new `tsconfig.json` file for each directory. After that, you should use this, in the **main** `tsconfig.json`:

```
"references": [
    { "path": "PATH/TO/EACH/OTHER/TSCONFIG.JSON/FILES" }
]
```

### Second

On top of that, you also must **add** this option to the `compilerOptions` of each **secondaries** `tsconfig.json` files:

```
"composite": true
```

### Third

Also, **use** `"include"` to point to each `.ts` files that that particular `tsconfig.json` will use:

```
"include": [
    "./homeWork.ts",
    "./myGame.ts"
]
```

or

```
"include": [
    "./*.ts" //Points to every .ts file inside that directory.
]
```

### Fourth

Now, you should be able compile it all, at once, using any of these commands from the same directory as the main `tsconfig.json`:

- `tsc --build`;
- `tsc -b //Alias for the above command`;
- `tsc -w -b //Above command, including the option -w for watching changes recursively`.

## Considerations

- Note that, using these commands, the compiler will go through each reference that each `tsconfig.json` may have;
- This might be a good way to avoid colison between the DOM and WebWorker libraries;
- The references always generate declaration files;
- Compile time gets slower, though I don't know if it is my mistake or a natural thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible within a single compilation.

You will have to run `tsc` twice with different `tsconfig.json` files or `-outDir` options.

Comment: Just found the solution to make it compile different `tsconfig.json` files, using just one command (TypeScript 3.0). I will be posting an answer, ASAP.